# Git submodule does not checkout the last revision of the branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-branch, git-submodules

I am working on a project having one git submodule (... and I am absolutely not familiar with that!) and I don't understand why it doesn't get the last revision of the checked-out branch!!!

Let me describe what I do more in details...

My `.gitmodules` is similar to that:

```
[submodule "MySubmodule"]
        path = MySubmodule
        url = ../my-sub-repo.git
        branch = master
```

Now I want to change the branch, not use anymore `master` but ''other''.

After cloning my "main" git repository, I first change my `.gitmodules` to

```
[submodule "MySubmodule"]
        path = MySubmodule
        url = ../my-sub-repo.git
        branch = other
```

Then, I initialize my submodule by running the following command:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I get the following output:

```
Submodule 'MySubmodule' (ssh://git@xxx.xxx.xxx:7999/project/my-sub-repo.git) registered for path 'MySubmodule'
Cloning into '/tmp/project/my-main-repo/MySubmodule'...
Submodule path 'MySubmodule': checked out '499ae4ccb7bf59c2c3acab5b63e1e6ff58b49ca4'
```

What is annoying to me here is the revision: `499ae4ccb7bf59c2c3acab5b63e1e6ff58b49ca4`!!! It is not the last one in my branch `other` on my repository `my-sub-repo`

If in my `.gitmodules` I change the `branch` by:

```
        branch = other@HEAD
```

I get the same result: not the last commit!!!

I found a workaround for this strange situation: if after the `git submodule update --init --recursive` I run:

```
git submodule update --remote
Submodule path 'MySubmodule': checked out '29ffbebe032badb8728729c7ab30e96e41fc0a84'
```

Now the expected revision is checked-out!!!

What I need to understand is why I don't get the lastest revision of the `other` branch when only running `git submodule update --init --recursive`? What makes git decide to use revision `499ae4ccb7bf59c2c3acab5b63e1e6ff58b49ca4`?

Thanks for help

Best regards
Phil

Comment: That's how submodules are *supposed* to work. (People don't like this, but it's how they're supposed to work.) The hash ID to use *in* the submodule is recorded in the superproject commits. The branch name, if you have one set, is really for the `update --remote` option. Note that after you use this option to update the submodule, you should build and test the superproject, then add each submodule (to record the new hash ID) and commit in the superproject (to record that you're declaring that this all works and that's what should be checked out in future).

Comment: I am not sure to understand "The hash ID to use in the submodule is recorded in the superproject commits": As I change the branch from ``master`` to ``other``, nothing is supposed to be "recorded in the superproject" regading this new branch: what is the logic behind that?

Comment: Who said anything about logic? :-) More seriously: when you make a commit in a regular repository sans submodules, the commit records *every file that should be used*. The same idea applies even if you have a submodule: submodule *S* is currently checked out at commit hash H. Branch names point to different hash IDs at different times, but hash H will, forever, mean *exactly those files*. So the superproject records hash H along with all the superproject's files. Later, checking out that commit in the superproject will extract commit H in the submodule, and all files will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

working with submodule is difficult at the beginning.
Lets take an example :

```
--repo@master@head
-----submodule1@detached@46
-----submodule2@detached@5
```

each submodule will be detached head in the super repo.
Before doing any modification you need to checkout the branch on the submodule you want to use( let say master)

```
--repo@master@head
-----submodule1@detached@master(48)
-----submodule2@detached@5
```

now if you commit the change in the submodule and the super repo your module1 is at 48 and the main repo to head master.

Now one of your colleague made a huge release on submodule2 master and this break your code.

This is the advantage of the detached head you can still work on your repo and keeping your module2 at the right state.
even with any pull and submodule update.

When you want to integrate the big release and fix the code with module2 you have to checkout the submodule2, fix any issue in the main repo and commit and link the submodule2 with the last version.

Bonus :
if you didn't checkout the submodule but you commit some change they will not appear on master or on any branch. they are "detached" of all branches. in this case you have to  :

```
Create a new branch from you last commit. 
Checkout master/orthebracnh you want
integrate the new branch into master
delete the newbranch
```